# Determinant in terms of certain $2\times 2$ minors

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, determinants

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with entries $a_{i,j}$. Define an $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix $B$ with entries $b_{i,j}=a_{1,1}a_{i+1,j+1}-a_{1,j+1}a_{i+1,1}$. Then $\det(B)=a_{1,1}^{n-2}\det(A)$.

I can prove this by direct computation, but it seems like something that may be well known or follow from other properties of determinants. Do you either know a reference for this result or know how to give a simple proof of it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodgson_condensation

Comment: Ah, maybe it is not quite exactly the same as Dodgson condensation, but it seems very close...

Comment: I once needed a reference for an easy but obscure matrix identity and found it in Muir’s Treatise on the Theory of Determinants (I think Google Books has full text).  These types of pursuits were much more fashionable back in the 19th century (as evidenced by the similarity to Dodgson condensation).  Apologies I don’t have time at the moment to check if it’s in there.

Comment: https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/primes2015/kazh-exp.pdf gives a direct proof (although a longish one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple proof is given in the [Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1328834p7152628) (it is entered as an "olympiade problem").

I reproduce the two-line proof for the record, with the change that $a_{11}\mapsto a_{nn}$:

Add the $n$-th row of $A$ to the $i$-th row, multiplied by $-a_{in}/a_{nn}$:
$$\det{A}= \left| \begin{array}{cccccc}
a_{1,1}-a_{n,1}\dfrac{a_{1,n}}{a_{n,n}} & \dots & a_{1,j}-a_{n,j}\dfrac{a_{1,n}}{a_{n,n}} & \dots & a_{1,n-1}-a_{n,n-1}\dfrac{a_{1,n}}{a_{n,n}} & 0 \\ 
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\ 
a_{i,1}-a_{n,1}\dfrac{a_{i,n}}{a_{n,n}} & \dots & a_{i,j}-a_{n,j}\dfrac{a_{i,n}}{a_{n,n}} & \dots & a_{i,n-1}-a_{n,n-1}\dfrac{a_{i,n}}{a_{n,n}} & 0 \\ 
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\ 
a_{n-1,1}-a_{n,1}\dfrac{a_{n-1,n}}{a_{n,n}} & \dots & a_{n-1,j}-a_{n,j}\dfrac{a_{n-1,n}}{a_{n,n}} & \dots & a_{n-1,n-1}-a_{n,n-1}\dfrac{a_{n-1,n}}{a_{n,n}} & 0 \\ 
a_{n,1} & \dots & a_{n,j} & \dots & a_{n,n-1} & a_{n,n}
\end{array} \right|$$
$$=a_{n,n} \cdot \left| \begin{array}{ccccc}
\dfrac{b_{1,1}}{a_{n,n}} & \dots & \dfrac{b_{1,j}}{a_{n,n}} & \dots & \dfrac{b_{1,n-1}}{a_{n,n}} \\ 
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\ 
\dfrac{b_{i,1}}{a_{n,n}} & \dots & \dfrac{b_{i,j}}{a_{n,n}} & \dots & \dfrac{b_{i,n-1}}{a_{n,n}} \\ 
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\ 
\dfrac{b_{n-1,1}}{a_{n,n}} & \dots & \dfrac{b_{n-1,j}}{a_{n,n}} & \dots & \dfrac{b_{n-1,n-1}}{a_{n,n}}
\end{array} \right|= \dfrac{1}{{a_{n,n}}^{n-2}} \cdot \det{B} $$

Comment: You are probably tired answering such questions, but how did you find it?

Comment: [this search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cdet%5C%20B%5C%20%3D%5C%20a_%7B11%20%7D%5E%7Bn-2%7D%5C%20%5Cdet%5C%20A%24&p=1) returns the AoPS link at the bottom of the first results page.

Comment: million of thanks, I did not know about this engine

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thanks for calling attention to this search engine and to Carlo for linking it!

Comment: Note: This requires some reasoning to justify that $a_{n,n}$ can be assumed to be invertible.

Answer (score 4):

This can also be done in terms of the [Schur complement determinant formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement).

The matrix $B$ is by definition $a_{1,1}A/{1}$, where $A/{1}$ is the Schur complement of $A$ with respect to the $1 \times 1$ submatrix with that one diagonal entry. The determinant formula for Schur complements says
$$
\det(A)=a_{1,1}\det(A/{1})=\frac{\det(B)}{a_{1,1}^{n-2}},
$$
which is what we wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @carlo-beenakker, @erick-wong, @quizzical, and @sam-hopkins for helpful answers and comments.

Investigating further, I found that the statement in the question appears to be a well-known result of Chio from his 1853 manuscript *Mémoire sur les fonctions connues sous le nom de résultantes ou de déterminans*. I was unable to obtain Chio's manuscript but found a summary of it in Muir's 1911 work *The Theory of Determinants in the Historical Order of Development, Volume II*. Footnote 2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2717v3) discusses the rendering of Chio's name. Sections 2 and 3 of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2014.04.010) discuss the relationship between Chio's result and a more general result stated without proof by Sylvester in his 1851 article *On the relation between the minor determinants of linearly equivalent quadratic functions*.

I found an appropriate reference to a proof to be Eves's 1966 textbook *Elementary Matrix Theory*, which includes the statement in this question as Theorem 3.6.1.